# Why clang tidy doesn't like assert in constexpr function?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, constexpr, suppress-warnings

I have a simple function,

```
int f(int x){
  assert( x > 0 );
  ... do something ...
}
```

The compiler and clang-tidy are happy with it.
Then I make the function constexpr,

```
constexpr int f(int x){
  assert( x > 0 );
  ... do something ...
}
```

clang-tidy now complains

> do not implicitly decay an array into a pointer; consider using `gsl::array_view` or an explicit cast instead [cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-array-to-pointer-decay,hicpp-no-array-decay]`.

At the beginning I was puzzled by it but now
I *suspect* this is caused by an `assert` that has a special implementation for constexpr context in C++14.

**Is that the case?**

If that is the case, it is a good sign that it is using a fancy definition of `assert` that is `constexpr` friendly. (see https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/05/18/asserts-in-constexpr-functions/)

**Is there a good way to workaround this warning or improve the code?**

At the moment I am suppressing the warning with this comment of mine: `// NOLINT(cppcoreguidelines-pro-bounds-array-to-pointer-decay,hicpp-no-array-decay) : allow c++14 constexpr-friendly assert`, but I might be missing something important.

Comment: Well, constexpr is trying to make a determination of the const at compile time. The assert is not allowing for it. Try a static_assert instead.   Andrzej has done more research on this topic. See https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2017/05/18/asserts-in-constexpr-functions/

Comment: Use static_assert and make sure all your other code is constexpr compatible too

Comment: @kalyanswaroop, `static_assert` isn't applicable because `constexpr` functions can be used at runtime as well. `x` isn't a constant expression. (There's a more fundamental reason that it still doesn't work in `consteval` either.)

Comment: @alfC just FYI, that link you posted is a patch specifically for C++11 `constexpr` assert compatibility. C++14 and up can just use a trivial `assert()` implementation just fine. see https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/da4Me58Ex

Comment: @Frank, thanks, yes I understand that the article is itself a workaround for C++11 but it is also the way learned that `assert` are by-default ok in `constexpr` functions in c++14, which is my case. Also because of the mysterious clang-tidy warning, I deduce that there is something special about the assert macro in a constexpr context in C++14, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: @alfC, My point is that there is nothing C++14-related going on here.

Comment: @Frank, ah, yes, except for the fact that the code should be perfectly ok in C++14 (and not in in C++11 because of the limitations of constexpr) and yet `clang-tidy` still complains for some detail.

Comment: @alfC In that case, unless https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/assert is mistaken, that guarantee was not introdcued until C++17.

Comment: @Frank I see. the articles mentioned C++14 I think. Do you mean because of the quote "The expression assert(E) is guaranteed to be a constant subexpression, ..."? Ok, in any case I would be interested to know how to avoid this warning with clang-tidy.